# Make Jenkins discover PR branch without automatically triggering build

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

**Attempt 1 : Trigger Jenkins build using Python API**

Using Jenkins Python API, I am able to trigger a jenkins build for a PR (`job.invoke()`)

```
JENKINS_URL = "<url>"
JENKINS_USERNAME = "<>"
JENKINS_PASSWORD = "<>"

class DevOpsJenkins:
    def __init__(self):
        self.jenkins_server = Jenkins(JENKINS_URL, username=JENKINS_USERNAME, password=JENKINS_PASSWORD)

    def build_job(self, name, build_no=None):
        job = self.jenkins_server[name]
        job.invoke(block=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NAME_OF_JOB = "<>/"
    pipelines = ['apache-centos-gpu']
    prs = [14]
    jenkins_obj = DevOpsJenkins()
    for i in range(len(prs)):
        for j in range(len(pipelines)):
            job_name = NAME_OF_JOB+pipelines[j]+"/PR-"+str(prs[i])
            jenkins_obj.build_job(job_name)
```

Provided, discover branch strategy is as follow
[image: discover_branch]

**Issue with Attempt 1 : Undesired Automatic trigger**

However, the issue with this is, it discovers the PR branches and automatically triggers build on them everytime a new PR is created or a new commit is pushed to the PR branch.

**Attempt 2 : Prevent branch discovery to stop automatic trigger**

To solve that, I changed the discover strategy so as to not discover anything
[image: no_discover]

As you can see in the empty behavior field.

**Result?** 
No branch is discovered. Not even PR branch. This prevents **automatic triggering** of PR builds. But this also prevents **manual triggering** of PRs. Basically, PR job can't be triggered anymore.

If I try the same above code with minor adjustments (of changing job name/pipeline) I get this error 
`jenkinsapi.custom_exceptions.UnknownJob`

So, the question is : **how should I ensure branches are discovered without automatically triggering the PRs?**

Why do I want to discover branches? So that I can **manually** trigger Jenkins builds.

I can't see any button which allows to enable/disable Automatic triggering for Jenkins builds.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the solution to this problem in [this](https://www.shellhacks.com/jenkins-scan-multibranch-pipeline-without-build/) site.

Quoting:

> Go to the configuration settings of your multibranch pipeline and in
>   the “Branch Sources” section click on the “Add property” and select
>   the property, named “Suppress automatic SCM triggering“.
>
> This will prevent Jenkins from triggering the builds every time it
>   discovers new branches.

Comment: after adding this property, will i have to manually scan multibranch pipeline for new branches or will it automatically scan them?

Comment: Scan rules remain the same, you can set it to automatically trigger the multibranch scan but it will never call the build afterwards.

Comment: Nope. With automatic SCM triggers, multibranch scan is not required. Because when a user creates a new PR [& thus a new branch], and pushes a commit to it, that will automatically result in Jenkins [scan that branch + build pipeline for that branch] However with suppress automatiic SCM triggering, Jenkins no longer gets that github event about a new branch + commit and hence it never discovers that branch either.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand very well your message. Have you read the link where I took this from? I don't see why github won't be receiving the event of a new branch. The only thing this property is avoiding is to trigger a build after we have an event.
You can have a look at the code here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/branch/NoTriggerBranchProperty.java#L41